# Want to highlight 'Mediawiki Syntax' on a Mediawiki page

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, geshi

I've been asking Goodle and Stackoverflow variation of this query:

- `Syntax highlighting of mediawiki syntax`

almost without exception I'm getting hits referring me to the Mediawiki [Extension:SyntaxHighlight](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Alternative_.3Csource.3E_tag) page.  Unfortunately that is the *question* in this case, not the answer.

I did find a hit on MoinMoin ironically that wiki has MediaWiki syntax highlighting.

What I'd like to be able to do is to use syntaxhighlight around some mediawiki page mark-up to demonstrate how different pages or sections can be set-up.  For now I'm using the `<syntaxhighlight lang="text" ... >`.

I'd like either a suitable "wiki"-highlight option or an workable alternative that will highlight some wiki markup.  Ideally it would be fantastic to say:

- `<syntaxhighlight lang="mediawiki" >` ... `</syntaxhighlight>`

I am surprised that this hasn't been asked before though.

---

***edit*** 2016-05-09:

As a work around I have settled on the following for the time being.  It isn't as *pretty* as having the final tag inside the syntaxhighlight but it gets the job done:

```
  ==  xml  ==

  <syntaxhighlight lang="text"  highlight="1,11">
  :<syntaxhighlight highlight="6" lang="xml">
  <tomcat-users ...>

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>

    <user username="admin" password="****" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
  </syntaxhighlight>
  <code><nowiki></syntaxhighlight></nowiki></code>
```

Which shows the closing `</syntaxhighlight>` tag outside the main box.

Answer (score 0):

In the core, **Extension:SyntaxHighlight** uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), and it is extensible to make your own "syntax highlighting" or find a [big set of other languages](http://pygments.org/languages/), take a look maybe you can find something useful, but I'm not sure that it will be something out of the box.

Comment: I understand.  It is _ironic_, I agree.  I think that is a "comment" and not an answer, of course.